# What does "whether synchronized I/O can be used with the associated file" mean?

Tags: files

From *Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment*:

> For `_PC_ASYNC_IO`, `_PC_PRIO_IO`, and `_PC_SYNC_IO`, the referenced file
>   must not be a directory.

```
Name of option   |   Indicates ...                          |name argument
_POSIX_SYNC_IO   |whether synchronized I/O can be used with |_PC_SYNC_IO
                  the associated file
```

So I assume the usage would be
`long return_value = pathconf("/a/path/filename",_PC_SYNC_IO)`.

It looks like it's a way to get a specific file's "setting".

Is this thing can be set to a file? How can I set it?

And what does *synchronized I/O* mean as to a file? I mean, I don't understand how *synchronized I/O* could be a setting of a file? Shouldn't it be a programming aspect thing instead of merely a "setting"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `pathconf` can vary depending on the file, for some of the arguments it can be given (`_PC_NAME_MAX`, `_PC_ASYNC_IO`, and a few others), but for most arguments the result is a platform-dependent constant. The values you retrieve using `pathconf` aren’t per-file settings, they’re properties of the system and the type of file; you can’t set them.

Synchronized I/O in this context refers to synchronous reads and writes from and to a file, as controlled by `O_SYNC` and related flags which can be specified on [`open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) calls. `pathconf(..., _PC_SYNC_IO)` will tell you whether those flags are supported (note that `O_SYNC` is always supposed to be supported on regular files anyway, regardless of the result of `pathconf`).

Comment: So no matter what file I put into `pathconf("/no/matter/what/file",_PC_SYNC_IO)`, the result would be the same? That's ... Oh god, then why requires the first argument at all..?

Comment: It’s a generic interface which supports a variety of settings, some of which are path-dependent (*e.g.* because they depend on the type of the file). You’re not really supposed to know ahead of time that any given setting is a constant ;-).